# Are electrons in higher energy orbits less entangled with the nucleus?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, quantum-entanglement

I understand that an electron in orbit is technically entangled with the nucleus. Is an electron with higher energy (further away from the nucleus) less entangled with the nucleus? Does a free electron remain partially entangled with the parent nucleus?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: With what measure would you be comparing the degree of entanglement so that you can say "less entangled" at all?

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is a perfectly clear question with a good answer below.

Answer (score 7):

The semiclassical approximation that there are "inner electrons" and "outer electrons" fails in this case. When we talk about "an electron," we are referring a discrete particle-like excitation in the "electron field," which is a property of the vacuum whose four complex-valued components obey the Dirac equation. A calcium nucleus, with charge $+20e$, can be made neutral by capturing twenty electrons from elsewhere.  But all of those electrons are indistinguishable from each other, even as they orbit (if you'll pardon the semiclassical language) the nucleus.

The energy eigenstates of an atom are states of the nucleus and the entire electron cloud.  The separation of the electron cloud into distinguishable electrons is an approximation.

A free electron doesn't have any memory of its parent nucleus, because all free electrons are indistinguishable. You may be able to construct a system where the free electron and the nucleus co-evolve in predictable ways, so that measurements of the one are correlated with measurements of the other.  That's what entanglement *is*, and why entanglement is delicate when the messy complicated environment gets involved.

Comment: Are the 20 electrons of a neutral calcium atom (at rest in the lab frame, not subjected to external EM fields, etc, etc) _really_ all indistinguishable?  Naively, that seems inconsistent with Pauli exclusion.

Comment: @zwol Pauli exclusion is a *consequence* of indistinguishability. There's just one electron field, which must be antisymmetric under exchange of all its particle-like excitations. In the nonrelativistic model, the exclusion principle has to be added in by hand. Spin has the same behavior: added in by hand to the Schrödinger equation, but arising naturally in the Dirac equation.

Comment: @zwol All electrons in the universe are indistinguishable.

Answer (score 0):

I question whether the proton and the electron (say in a hydrogen atom) are entangled on any basis. There is no requirement, for example, for their spins to be aligned parallel or anti-parallel.

On the other hand, I would say the 2 ground state electrons in a helium atom are entangled, certainly on a spin basis.  Probably in momentum too.  Within the orbital, they are indistinguishable even though they have opposite spins.

So I would answer the original question by saying the electron orbital has nothing to do with entanglement relative to the nucleus.

Keep in mind that there may be elements of entanglement between baryons (protons, neutrons) in larger nuclei, although generally not maximal entanglement. There are of course limits on entanglement shared between components of any quantum system.  The monogamy relations come into play, for example.

Interestingly, it has recently been shown that baryons exhibit color and other entanglement between their constituent quarks/gluons. If you are interested in this, check out: [Probing the onset of maximal entanglement inside the proton in diffractive DIS](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.03069)